# Redirect to same/different html page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm facing problem in redirecting to html page. My scenario is :

I have two pages named First.html & Second.html. Second.html contains a link to go back i.e previous page. i have define `<b>href=""</b>` attribute of that link. And i call a JavaScript function `goBack()` on it's `onClick()` event. And in that I written code to redirect using `<b>window.location.href</b>`. Bcoz, I want to do something like below :

---

**1.** When request came from First.html, i have to go back to First.html from Second.html

**2.** When request came from Second.html, i have to go to same page, i.e., Second.html.   Second.html's div's contents are changes dynamically using JavaScript, but the page is same.

---

I have tried following options :

1. `window.location.href`
2. `document.location.href`
3. `location.href`
4. `window.url`
5. `window.location.replace(url)`
6. `location.assign(url);`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: awesome! What's next?

Comment: So, where's your JavaScript and/or jQuery? Where are you stuck? What do you want us to *help* with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution by myself.

In first.html

```
<a href="Second.html?p=First">
```

In Second.html

```
<a href="" onclick=" return goBack()">Back</a>
<script>
    var p = window.location.href;
    var pre = p.substring(p.lastIndexOf('?') + 3, p.length);
    var same = "";
    //It changes the contents of Second.html' div tag
    someFunction()
</script>
```

In js file

There is an event on button which come by calling someFunction(), in that

```
$(document).on('click', '.button1', function() {
    // some extra code
    same = "Second";
}

var diff;
function goBack() {
    if (same == "First") {
        diff = pre;
        pre = same;
    }
    if (pre == same) {
        location.href = "Second.html?p=" + diff;
        same = "";
    } else if (pre != 'Second') {
        location.assign("" + pre + ".html");
        diff = pre;
    } else {
        location.assign("" + diff + ".html");
    }
    return false;
}
```